# Add background line to plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly object written in R that I want to place a 1:1 prediction accuracy line on. This works great!

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = c(1, 35), y = c(1, 35), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~mpg + rnorm(32, 0, 3), color = ~factor(cyl),
            mode = "markers", type = "scatter")
```

[image: first plot]

Except the line is a little bit heavy. Unfortunately if I try to change its visual appearance, it gets confused with the aesthetics in my other layer.

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = c(1, 35), y = c(1, 35), showlegend = FALSE,
            color = "grey", alpha = 0.8) %>%
  add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~mpg + rnorm(32, 0, 3), color = ~factor(cyl),
            mode = "markers", type = "scatter")

## Warning messages:
## 1: In colScale(as.character(color[[i]])) :
##   Some values were outside the color scale and will be treated as NA
## 2: In colScale(as.character(color[[i]])) :
##   Some values were outside the color scale and will be treated as NA
## 3: In colScale(as.character(color[[i]])) :
##   Some values were outside the color scale and will be treated as NA
```

[image: trying to make it grey]

Is there something I'm missing here? Namely, a way to isolate aesthetics to each layer?

Comment: try: I("grey") instead of "grey"

Comment: Hey, that worked! A bit unintuitive, though I get now why it does